# Replace a Date with a UNIX Timestam while leaving the rest of the line as it is

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

I've got a Line like this

> copy to somewhere from somewhere at Wed 13 Apr 10:18:25 CEST 2016 filesize ...

I want to transform the Date into a Unix Timestamp. While the rest of the line remains the same. I want to do this for the complete file. The only way I can imagine is extracting the date transforming it and create a new File and fill in the Timestamp.

Comment: Yeah, good idea! Show us the command line you tried, otherwise some will think you want us to write your code...

Comment: Is 'filesize' ends the line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if 'filesize' ends a line in your file. You did end the line with it, but you also wrote '...' which makes me wonder if there is more content to come. Details like these are crucial when you ask a question which involves text manipulation.

Assuming 'filesize' ends a line, the following code might be of help, otherwise it will be just a helpful pattern for you to modify according to your needs.

```
while read -r line; do
    # The part containing the date and the file size.
    details_str="${line#*at }"
    # The date part.
    date_str="${details_str% *}"
    # The file size.
    file_size="${details_str#$date_str }"

    # Arrange date part, so it can be acceptable by 'date'
    # [Correct] 10:18:25 Wed 13 Apr CEST 2016
    # [Incorrect] Wed 13 Apr 10:18:25 CEST 2016
    read -r d n m t z y <<< "$date_str"
    printf -v date_str '%s %s %s %s %s %s' "$t" "$d" "$n" "$m" "$z" "$y"

    # Convert date part to milliseconds since epoch.
    millis=$(date --date="$date_str" '+%s')

    # Print formatted line.
    printf '%s %s %s\n' "${line% $details_str}" "$millis" "$file_size"

done < /path/to/your/file
```

To test it, I created the following file:

```
copy to somewhere1 from somewhere at Wed 13 Apr 10:18:25 CEST 2016 20K
copy to somewhere2 from somewhere at Wed 13 Apr 09:14:25 CEST 2016 30K
copy to somewhere3 from somewhere at Wed 13 Apr 12:18:25 CEST 2016 40K
```

Test ( script name is ***sof*** ):

```
./sof 
copy to somewhere1 from somewhere at 1460535505 20K
copy to somewhere2 from somewhere at 1460531665 30K
copy to somewhere3 from somewhere at 1460542705 40K
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this one, your assumption was right, Filesize ends the line. I didn't even know bash can do this text manipulation thx for showing this one to me.